# Delete lines from file with SED or AWK

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed, awk

Ive seen many variations, very confused on how to solve these 3 problems.

1. deleting all rows except the first from a file
2. deleting a row from file with a line number
3. deleting rows from a file with a range of line numbers

Answer (score 32):

Using sed:

Delete 1st line:

```
sed '1d' file-name
```

Delete 10th line:

```
sed '10d' file-name
```

Delete line # 5 to 10

```
sed '5,10d' file-name
```

All above sed commands will write output on stdout that you can redirect to another file if you want or use `-i` flag of sed to inline edit the file.

Comment: To delete *all lines but the first*, `sed '2,$d' filename`, or `sed '1!d' filename`, or `sed -n '1p' filename`.

Comment: @Beta, first two are exactly right, but the third will print the first line only.

Comment: @dubiousjim: `Print first line only` is same as `delete all lines but the first` that's why `sed -n '1p'` is also correct.

Comment: @anubhava, sorry, mental glitch. I thought you were trying to do something else; don't know on what basis I thought so.

Comment: Lifesaver for loading a sql dump without destroying / creating the table.  Many thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

With awk:

```
# delete line 1
awk 'NR == 1 {next} {print}' file

# delete line number stored in shell variable $n
awk -v n=$n 'NR == n {next} {print}' file

# delete between lines $a and $b inclusive
awk -v m=$a -v n=$b 'm <= NR && NR <= n {next} {print}' file
```

To save a few chars, `{print}` can be replaced just with `1`

To overwrite the original file, you have to do something like this

```
awk '...' file > tmpfile && mv tmpfile file
```

Comment: ok this is working but the lines are just printing out and not saving to the file?

Comment: To delete line 1, use awk 'NR!=1'. The default action is to print the line. All of your '{next} {print}' terms can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use bash if your system has it. The basic idea behind is to set a count and incrementing this count while iterating the file.

1) deleting all rows except the first from a file

```
read -r line < file; echo "$line" > temp && mv temp file
```

2) deleting a row from file with a line number

```
declare -i count=0
while read -r line
do
  ((count++))
  case "$count" in
    10) continue;;
    * ) echo "$line";;
  esac
done < file > temp && mv temp file
```

3) deleting rows from a file with a range of line numbers eg from 10 to 20

```
declare -i count=0
while read -r line
do
  ((count++))
  if (( $c < 10 && $c > 20 ));then
    echo "$line";;
  fi
done < file > temp && mv temp file
```

Comment: The way you use it, `read -r` will still strip leading and trailing whitespace. You need to do `IFS= read -r line`. Furthermore note that from a shell script this method is faster for small files because it avoids a fork, but slower for large files because `read` is inherently inefficient and usually reads one byte at a time or does one read and lseek call per invocation and string processing in bash tends to be inefficient (less so in other shells).

Comment: @jilles, thanks I forgot about IFS= on these cases. And yes, i do know that `read` is inefficient on large files with `bash`. If OP's files are large sizes and performance is an issue, then use a better tool.