# Delete lines from file

Tags: text, sed, awk, gawk

I have a question similar to this one:
[Delete lines from file with SED or AWK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721524/delete-lines-from-file-with-sed-or-awk)

how can I delete rows that start with 3 and 5 and everything in between in this file:

```
ssadfsadfsdf
asdfsadf
asdfsadf
asdfsadf
asdfsdf
1 z z z lkj klj lkj
2 satan er kaerleikur lkj lkj lkj
3 z z z
4 asdflj asd sdf
5 z z z
6 asdf sdaf asdf
7 z z z lkj lkj lkj
8 sdf safd asdf
9 z z z
```

If the answer is clearly elsewhere I will delete this question.

what if it looked liked this:

```
asd        ssadfsadfsdf
asd        asdfsadf
asd        asdfsadf
asd        asdfsadf
asd        asdfsdf
asd        1 z z z lkj klj lkj
asd        2 satan er kaerleikur lkj lkj lkj
asd        3 z z z
asd        4 asdflj asd sdf
asd        5 z z z
asd        6 asdf sdaf asdf
asd        7 z z z lkj lkj lkj
asd        8 sdf safd asdf
asd        9 z z z
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an awk *range pattern* to skip line matching pattern 1 up to pattern 2:

```
awk '$1 == 3, $1 == 5 { next }; { print }' INFILE
```

I do a numerical comparison on field `$1` instead of a regular expression such as `/^3/` because that would also match '30', '31', etc.

If the number is the second field of the line (as in your edited example input), just change `$1` to `$2`. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: And if I would want to delete all lines below a certain number then I do: awk '$1 < 5, { next }; { print }' INFILE That is if the first field would be a numerical index.

Answer (score 3):

A quick Google gave me this as seconds answer:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/sed-howto-remove-lines-paragraphs/

```
$ sed '/WORD1/,/WORD2/d' input.txt > output.txt
```

To make sure it's matching "beginning of line" like you said, you can start the pattern with the `^` symbol.

If you're using Vim (which has sed built in) you can do a `range command` like:

```
:/^3.*/,/^5.*/ d
```

where d is the delete command, and `:/exp1/,/exp2/` the range.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^3/ {del=1}
     (del==0) {print}
     /^5/ {del=0}' FILE
```

Comment: Works also but line starting with 5 stays so I put ^6 instead.

Comment: just move /^5/ matching line before (del==0) condition

Comment: In Mawk, this deletes everything up to and including the line starting with `5`. Moving the `^5` one line up causes it to keep that line.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$2!~/^[3|5]/' yourFile
```

will do it for you.

see the test below:

```
kent$  echo "asd        ssadfsadfsdf
asd        asdfsadf
asd        asdfsadf
asd        asdfsadf
asd        asdfsdf
asd        1 z z z lkj klj lkj
asd        2 satan er kaerleikur lkj lkj lkj
asd        3 z z z
asd        4 asdflj asd sdf
asd        5 z z z
asd        6 asdf sdaf asdf
asd        7 z z z lkj lkj lkj
asd        8 sdf safd asdf
asd        9 z z z"|awk '$2!~/^[3|5]/'
```

output:

```
asd        ssadfsadfsdf
asd        asdfsadf
asd        asdfsadf
asd        asdfsadf
asd        asdfsdf
asd        1 z z z lkj klj lkj
asd        2 satan er kaerleikur lkj lkj lkj
asd        4 asdflj asd sdf
asd        6 asdf sdaf asdf
asd        7 z z z lkj lkj lkj
asd        8 sdf safd asdf
asd        9 z z z
```

Comment: I interpret the question such that the "4" line should also be deleted.

Comment: Yes, how would you make 3 and 5 and everything in between disappear. Awk syntax is nearly not human readable.