# sed: How do I delete the first 100 lines of a text file

Tags: sed

I would like to delete the first 100 lines of a text file using sed. I know how delete to the first line by using:

```
sed '1d' filename
```

or the 100th line by typing

```
sed '100d' filename
```

How do I specify a range? I thought something like this would work:

```
sed '1:100d' filename
```

However, this obviously didn't work. Can someone show me how to specify a range? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `,` rather than `:`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete lines from file with SED or AWK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721524/delete-lines-from-file-with-sed-or-awk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work in gnu sed

```
sed '1,100d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` can also be used to print data based on conditions related to rows.

Like: Following will print the lines (Records in terms of awk) whose number is greater than 100.

```
awk 'NR>100' inputfile
```

One can also use other conditions like:

```
awk 'NR==100' inpuftile    #this will print the 100th line
awk 'NR<100' inputfile     #this will print  1-99th line
awk 'NR>100' inputfile     #this will print from 101st line onwards
awk 'NR>=100' inputfile    #this will print from 100th onwards
```

Answer (score 0):

try: following too:

```
sed -n '1,100p'  Input_file
```