# Best way to convert .ipynb to .py in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm looking for a good way to convert .ipynb to .py files in VSCode. So far I've tried:

- the "Export As" Option built into vscode. Not ideal as it produces the following at the start of the script, as well as "Run Cell", "Run Below", etc. buttons/links:

> "To add a new cell, type '# %%' To add a new markdown cell, type '# %%
> [markdown]' %% from IPython import get_ipython"

- nbconvert. I usually insert this as a command in the script itself (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19779226/14198216) so it's automatically converted and saved once run. But this also leaves "Run Cell" etc, as well as execution markings (ex: "In [1]")
- jupytext. I also usually insert this as a command. At the start of the .py, it produces:

> -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
> --- jupyter:    jupytext:
> text_representation:

Is there a nice, minimalist solution that doesn't insert a bunch of gunk (which needs to be manually edited out) in the .py version of my notebooks and can be easily/automatically executed from the notebook itself? This could also be setting tweaks that I'm currently unaware of that can make one of the things I mentioned work better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on your system can easily follow-up your jupytext command with [a sed command to remove the first line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5721563/8508004). Jupytext is nice in that it allows [a nice round-trip ability](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html). However, I don't know if the round-trip conversion works as advertised without the normal first line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can add the following settings in "`settings.json`", the generated python file will not have "Run Cell", "Run Above", "Debug Cell":

```
"jupyter.codeLenses": " ",
```

[image]

Comment: that did not work out for me using `nbconvert`

Answer (score 29):

You need to install the Jupyter package:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter

Then open "Command Palette" (⇧⌘P) and search for this line: 
Jupyter: Convert/Export to Python script \

[image]

Comment: It is called now 'Jupyter: Convert to Python script'

Comment: This solution produces a file that includes the "Interactive mode" cruft like "'# %%' " that the question asker specifically said they don't want. However, as another answer indicates, these are quite easy to remove.

Answer (score 9):

In VSCode v1.75.1, if you right-click on a notebook file (.ipynb) in the file explorer side panel, you will have an option called 'Import Notebook to Script'. This worked for me. [Image shows options after right-click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0R09H.png)

Comment: I don't have this option. Maybe you installed an extension that adds this option?

Answer (score 3):

Converting to .py by Command Palette will open a file, just select one of the markdowns # %%, change all occurrences (Ctrl+F2), and remove all # %% at once. This will remove all "Run Cell" etc... Save file.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to modify your `settings.json` file (or don't know where it is stored), you can actually change how python files are exported through the VSCode IDE.

Bring up settings (`ctrl + ,`) or click the big cog on the bottom left and search for "jupyter code". The option you want to unselect is `Jupyter > Interactive Window > Code Lens: Enable`

[How to find the setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOIS0.png)

Now when you [export a notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrqAj.png), it should remove that option the run a cell although the %'s will still be there.

Answer (score 1):

I found that there is a way to export right within VS Code:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py

> ### Export a Jupyter notebook
>
> In addition to opening a Jupyter notebook, you can also use one of the
> following commands from the Command Palette (⇧⌘P) to export content
> from a Python file in VS Code to a Jupyter notebook (with the `.ipynb`
> extension).
>
> - **Jupyter: Export Current Python File as Jupyter Notebook**: creates a Jupyter notebook from the contents of the current file, using the `# %%` and `# %% [markdown]` delimiters to specify their respective cell types.
> - **Jupyter: Export Current Python File and Output as Jupyter Notebook**: creates a Jupyter notebook from the contents of the current file and includes output from code cells.
> - **Jupyter: Export Interactive Window as Jupyter Notebook:** creates a Jupyter notebook from the contents of the Python Interactive window.
>
> After exporting the contents, VS Code displays a prompt through which you can open the notebook in a browser.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: weird. I cannot find the Export option.

Comment: @Newbie, even after doing `Ctrl+Shift+P` (Windows) or `⇧⌘P` (MacOS) and then typing in "Export"?

Comment: @Sterling found it! thx!